# lxml XPath - how to get concatenated text from node

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xpath, lxml

I have a node like

```
<a class="someclass">
Wie
<em>Messi</em>
einen kleinen Jungen stehen lässt
</a>
```

How do I construct an XPath to get `["Wie Messi einen kleinen Jungen stehen lässt"]` instead of `["Wie","Messi","einen kleinen Jungen stehen lässt"]`?

I am using python lxml.html function with XPath.

Tried combinations

1. `//a/node()/text()`
2. `//a/descendant::*/text()`
3. `//a/text()`

But it didn't help. Any solutions?

I was thinking of another approach where I somehow get the "inner html" of the `<a>` element (which in the above case will be `"Wie <em>Messi</em> einen kleinen Jungen stehen lässt"`) and remove the `<em>` tags from the html.

Still trying to figure out how to get innerhtml (Javascript, anyone?) from XPath.

Comment: If you post your solution below you can (after a day or so) indeed accept your own answer. However, your approach does not yet seem ideal to me. `child::` is not an attribute it's an axis. And it's the default axis, too, so that `//a/child::*` is the same as `//a/*`.

Comment: The `child::` prefix is actually optional. You can use it for clarity, but you can safely omit it. You can use this: `doc.xpath('//a/*')` which selects *all child elements* of `<a>`. You probably are aware that this will *not* select the *text* children of `<a>`.

Comment: @Tomalak Apparently they are not the same. Read the examples above that I tried, to no avail. But hey! It's a workaround. May not be the ideal approach.

Comment: @zenCoder The `replace()` approach is actually pretty hideous and wrong. Don't do that. "But it's a work-around" is no excuse, especially since the correct alternatives are so straight-forward.

Answer (score 5):

XPath is a selection language, so what it can do is select nodes. If there are separate nodes in the input then you will get a list of separate nodes as the selection result.

You'll need the help of your host language - Python in this case - to do things beyond that scope (like, merging text nodes into a singe string).

You need to find all `<a>` elements and join their individual text descendants. That's easy enough to do:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse("path/to/file")

for a in doc.xpath("//a"):
    print " ".join([t.strip() for t in a.itertext()])
```

prints

```
Wie Messi einen kleinen Jungen stehen lässt
```

---

As paul correctly points out in the comments below, you can use XPath's `normalize-space()` and the whole thing gets even simpler.

```
for a in doc.xpath("//a"):
    print a.xpath("normalize-space()")
```

Comment: what about `print a.xpath('normalize-space(.)')` inside the loop?

Comment: @paultrmbrth That would work as well! (I didn't expect you could select function results with lxml, so I din't try that.)

Comment: @paultrmbrth Thank you Paul for the right answer! I used your solution finally.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the *string value* of the `<a>` node instead of using `text()`, you will get a concatenation of the string value of all child nodes, instead of individual text nodes.

Try using simply

```
//a
```

And *reading the node as a string* in your host language. In Python you can use a DOM function as mentioned by @Tomalak to obtain the string value. In *lxml* you can use [.text_content()](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods):

```
tree.XPath("//a)").text_content()
```

Within XPath, you can use a *type* function:

```
string(//a)
```

Comment: *"you will get a concatenation of the string value of all child nodes"* No, you won't. `//a` will select  all `<a>` nodes, and nothing else. You could use the `textContent` DOM property in the host language to get the concatenation of all child text nodes, but that's not XPath anymore.

Comment: @Tomalak *if* you get the string value. Maybe it wasn't clear, but I was referring exactly to the conversion to string in the host language.

Comment: @Tomalak I didn't write an identical answer. I edited it and a duplicate showed up. No idea why.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see. That's somewhat ambiguously put indeed.

Comment: BTW I just stumbled on the same post-duplicating bug. o_O